# Limit of $d\rightarrow 4$ of a function in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, calculus, dimensional-regularization

In Peskin & Schroeder section 12.1 equation 12.15 we compute the function
$$
\frac{-3\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^{d/2} \Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}\frac{(1-b^{d-4})}{d-4}\Lambda^{d-4}
$$
Now when we take the limit $d\rightarrow 4$, they arrive at the function
$$
-\frac{3\lambda^2}{16\pi^2}\log{\frac{1}{b}}
$$

I can't seem to be able to derive the limit. I get the correct prefactor but I don't see how the logarithmic function comes about.

Comment: [L'Hospital's rule?!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: Well, that was embarassing. Thanks for the hint! I'll type the answer below.

Comment: This is not a Physics question. It's pure Mathematics.

Comment: @Frobenius yes I agree, but the question being in a very commonly studied physics textbook I think it is apropriate to post it here.

Comment: Ok, I retract the close vote.

Comment: Did you mean $(4\pi)^{d/2}$? It's the only way to explain why the denominator is $16\pi^2$ instead of $256\pi^4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other terms are trivial, I will calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{d \to 4}\frac{1-b^{d-4}}{d-4}$ only. Let $x:=d-4$, then lim becomes

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-b^x}{x-0}=-\frac{db^x}{dx}|_{x=0}=-\frac{de^{x \ln b}}{dx}|_{x=0}=-e^{x}|_{x=0}\ln b = \ln\frac{1}{b}$

Actually it is more a calculus, rather than the physics.

Comment: Consider to use \ln in math mode.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Oh, Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I will write the coefficient seperately. For $d\rightarrow 4$ we have
$$
\frac{-3\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)}\rightarrow\frac{-3\lambda^2}{16\pi^2}
$$
then $\Lambda^{d-4}\rightarrow 1$ and finally the important part
$$
\frac{(1-b^{d-4})}{d-4} = \frac{1-e^{\log(b^{d-4})}}{d-4}=\frac{1-e^{(d-4)\log b}}{d-4}
$$
Now using L'Hospital
$$
\frac{1-e^{(d-4)\log b}}{d-4}\rightarrow \frac{ -\;e^{d-4}\log b}{1}\rightarrow -\log b = \log{\frac{1}{b}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Define $d=4-\epsilon$, then
$$b^{d-4} = e^{-\epsilon \log b}\approx1-\epsilon\log b$$